# installing shopify-cli on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shopify, shopify-app

I tried installing the Shopify app CLI through the command:

```
gem install shopify-cli
```

Output:

```
ERROR:  Error installing shopify-cli:
        "theme-check-language-server.bat" from theme-check conflicts with C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/theme-check-language-server.bat
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I get the same message but it asks me to `Overwrite the executable? [yN]` afterwards and the installation finish OK at the end. Is this missing on your end? ![refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmDVH.jpg)

Comment: Yes, it's missing, it does not even give me the option to overwrite anything.

Comment: Try using CMD with admin privileges and if that doesn't help try to delete the gem and install it fresh. (check if existing files are there after the gem delete and if they are remove them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit this site maybe it's helpful to you.

https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/tools/cli

Follow bellow Steps for CLI:-

Step 1: Install new requirementsAnchor link to section titled "Step 1: Install new requirements"
In addition to the requirements for Shopify CLI 2.x, Shopify CLI 3.x requires Node.js 14.17.0 or higher. If you use macOS, then Homebrew will install Node.js for you when you upgrade to the latest version of Shopify CLI.

For a complete list of requirements, refer to Install Shopify CLI.

Step 2: Uninstall Shopify CLI 2.xAnchor link to section titled "Step 2: Uninstall Shopify CLI 2.x"
Consider uninstalling the previous version of Shopify CLI. Uninstalling the previous version avoids any collisions between the two versions.

If you want to keep both versions of Shopify CLI installed, then refer to Using both Shopify CLI 2.x and 3.x to learn how to work with both versions in the same environment.

Shopify CLI can be removed from your system using the same package manager that you used to install it:

Terminal

gem uninstall shopify-cli
If you’re using a legacy version of Shopify CLI (lower than 0.9.0), then you need to uninstall it manually.

Step 3: Install Shopify CLI 3.xAnchor link to section titled "Step 3: Install Shopify CLI 3.x"
Shopify CLI is managed as a set of Node.js packages:

@shopify/cli
@shopify/theme

You can install these packages using Homebrew on macOS, or by installing the packages globally on Windows or Linux.

Note
apt, Yum, and RubyGems installations are no longer supported.

MACOSAnchor link to section titled "MacOS"
You can install Shopify CLI on macOS using Homebrew.

You need to add Shopify's third-party repositories to Homebrew using brew tap before you can install Shopify CLI.

Terminal

brew tap shopify/shopify
brew install shopify-cli

Note
Homebrew installs all of the requirements for running Shopify CLI, including Ruby, Node.js, and Git, for you.

WINDOWS AND LINUXAnchor link to the section titled "Windows and Linux"
To install Shopify CLI for themes, install the @shopify/cli and @shopify/theme Node.js packages globally using the command line.

Terminal

npm install -g @shopify/cli @shopify/theme
Step 4: Verify the installationAnchor link to the section titled "Step 4: Verify the installation"
To verify that Shopify CLI is installed properly, run the following command:

Comment: Your answer would very much benefit from using back tics - ` - to format things like `gem uninstall shopify-cli`

Answer (score 0):

Run command line as administrator. Then executing

```
gem install shopify-cli
```

will give you an option to override `theme-check-language-server.bat` and `theme-check.bat`. Confirm with `y` to override.

[image: command line logs]

Solution credit to [drip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2329464/drip).